# Unable to output the value of a key in GET HTTP method through a PHP file

Tags: php, html

I have an HTML page with a search box and a submit button. 
On clicking of submit button,the value entered in search box gets submitted in GET HTTP method and I am redirected to a PHP file, where I want to output the value entered in search box.
I have written the following code, but it did not work. Please help.

My index.html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <h1><b>Total Pay Company</b></h1>
            <form action="abc.php" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="product" placeholder="Search Products" style="width: 178px; height: 26px">
            <button type="submit" style="height: 31px; width: 72px; border:none">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </center>
    </body>
 </html>
```

My abc.php file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
       <title>Redirect</title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <h1>you searched for<b><?php print($_GET['product'])?></b></h1>
   </body>
 </html>
```

When I run my index.html file on the server, and give input in the search bar, and click on Submit, it gives the following result :

[image: Output of the above code]

Please help me through this.

Comment: There is a semicolon missing after ($_GET['product']). Also a space after that semicolon...

Comment: Also add this in the begin of abc.php: error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); and see if it prints an error.

Comment: Please also add print_r($_GET); to the page and see if it outputs anything. Also in your form the input tag should close with />